# VB - Raising events from another class correctly

Tags: vb.net, events

I know there is a lot of information regarding the above, but I do not grasp how to do this correctly, so I thought using a real life problem may help to click  it for me and others.

So in class A I have defined an event method

```
Public Sub textChangedMethod(ByVal textedChanged As Boolean)
  ' do some code on properties of this class only
End Sub
```

What I need to happen is I need some other class to raise this method,

I have a concept but its totally wrong.

At the moment I pass an instance of class A to the another class so it can reference the event (**this must be wrong**)

```
Dim UI As New newClassDialog(Me) 'class A
```

In this new class I have the event handler

```
Public Event textChanged(ByVal textedChanged As Boolean)
```

So in the constructor of the new class I can now add the handler

```
Public Sub New(ByRef classA As Class A)

   ' This call is required by the designer.
   InitializeComponent()

   AddHandler textChanged, AddressOf classA.textChangedMethod

End Sub
```

Now of course I can raise the event like so

```
RaiseEvent textChanged(True)
```

Basically passing in the class seems ridiculous in my eyes, so using this example is there a 'proper' way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There is not a lot of context there and the text conflates *raising* an event and *consuming* an event a little (`Public Sub textChangedMethod` is not an event definition but an event handler).  What it sounds like is that you are bubbling up  an event from Class A from this second class.  What these are would be helpful to know (I suspect one or more is a form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are inverting the roles. In this context the class that raises the event shouldn't know who handles the event. It is the responsability of class that instantiate the newClassDialog to add the event handler for the events raised by the called class

```
Dim UI As New newClassDialog(Me) 
AddHandler UI.textchanged, AddressOf Me.textChangedMethod
```

Comment: Thank you - its better as now I am not sending the class through and the public event is created in the newClassDialog class so therefore I only need to raise the event from that class now, I understand, thanks.

Comment: I would remove `(Me)` from your code as it suggests wrongly that you need to pass the class still!

Comment: Sending the class through the constructor was wrong also because only an instance of the class passed (or a derived one) could handle the event. It couples the class that raises the event to a specific type..

Comment: `Me` enforce the fact that the method passed is a method of the current instance. Not required right, but I fail to see how this could lead to think that the calling class is required

Comment: its not wrong but it is using the question context if people are following it